# Flink Windows HA

Tags: apache-flink

I'm working on apache flink(1.3.1) for data streaming and I have to setup it under Windows Server 2012 R2, I have a problem on the Flink HA setup. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here are the setup details, I have 5 servers, 2 for job managers HA, 2 for task managers HA and last one (Resource server) for saving all the recovery, savepoints or checkpoints files.

1. I have mapped the Resource Server as 'Y' network drive in all others
   server.
2. In flink-conf.yaml
   **high-availability.storageDir: file:///cygdrive/Y/flink-recovery**
3. It can access the Resource Server from Cygwin terminal with the path 'cygdrive/Y/flink-recovery'

Problem: When I run the start-cluster.sh command under Cygwin, the Flink HA will create a folder 'c:/cygdrive/Y/flink-recovery' in all the Flink servers instead of creating recovery files in the Resource Server.

I know the 'hdfs://' protocol an alternative for the Storage directory setting, but can the 'file://' protocol work in Flink HA?

Comment: The path to the checkpoint directory needs to be accessible from all machines in the cluster. That could be a file:// URI if you have a distributed file system mounted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using "bin/statrt-cluster.sh" to start the cluster in Cygwin will always create local files.
If I use "bin/jobmanager.sh start cluster IP", and other nodes use "bin/taskmanager.sh start" it can access the network drive.

I think "bin/start-cluster.sh" command will run as administrator. 
I have tried that run as the administrator, it can't list the network drive, but the run as a user can list the network drive in Cygwin.

Thanks